# Creating your own Validators in JSF 1.2 with Facelets 1.1.12

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, facelets

I was reviewing the following [link](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=121&thread=40846) and found out that `javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorTag` is deprecated and replaced by ValidatorELTag, however I can't seem to find any good information about this.

I want to create a Regular Expression Validator which takes input: regex and error message.

Meaning I would want to have a control like this:

```
<regexValidator for="myControl" check="([a-Z]^)" errorMessage="Your input contained incorrect characters" />
```

Now the given link above shows how to do a little part of this, but a whole lot has changed since that was written and methods are deprecated, how do i approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Creating a Custom Validator](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnauw.html) in the [JEE5 Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/index.html). The [Creating a Custom Tag](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnauw.html#bnauy) section details how to implement your `ValidatorELTag` class.

---

```
for="myControl"
```

I doubt you'll need this attribute (I'm not sure how you'd make use of it). The validator will be set on the parent control. `for` attributes are usually only used when one control refers to another, as in the label component.

---

EDIT: I misread the question; the answer above applies to JSPs (those tag-related classes in core JSF 1.2 are for JSPs only; **Facelets has its own tag system**; the good news is that you don't need a Java class specifically for defining the tag).

Sample validator:

```
public class RegexValidator implements Validator, StateHolder {
  private boolean isTransient;
  private String regex;

  public String getRegex() { return regex; }
  public void setRegex(String regex) { this.regex = regex; }

  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
      throws ValidatorException {
    //TODO: throw ValidatorException if not valid
  }

  //TODO: implement remaining StateHolder methods...
}
```

This validator is then registered in the `faces-config.xml`:

```
  <validator>
    <validator-id>regex.validator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>val.RegexValidator</validator-class>
  </validator>
```

You then [add a tag library](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib) to the app (e.g. `WEB-INF/facelets/foo.taglib.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Facelet">
  <namespace>http://demo</namespace>
  <tag>
    <tag-name>regexValidator</tag-name>
    <validator>
      <validator-id>regex.validator</validator-id>
    </validator>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Add a `xmlns:demo="http://demo"` declaration to any Facelets views you want to use the tag library in; your validator tag will start in the form `<demo:regexValidator ...`; attributes will be picked up through introspection of the validator class.

Comment: It doesn't find <demo:regexValidator = error on line 87 at column 30: Namespace prefix demo on regexValidator is not defined.

Comment: Also, why do you implement  StateHolder ?

Comment: The error is an XML parsing error - the `demo` namespace prefix is defined by adding the `xmlns:demo="<namespace>"` where `<namespace>` matches the namespace of the tag library. As to `StateHolder`, the view components (and their attributes) may not be kept in RAM between requests, so property values must be saved via the `StateManager` - in the demo code, the value of `regex` would need to be saved or it would be `null` when the view was restored when the form was submitted; it would _not_ be set again from the XML definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the piece I forgot to add to my code that tripped me up...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces/foo.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You'll also want to change `check="([a-Z]^)"` to `regex="..."`

I like this approach because there's no need to extend `ValidatorELTag`.  I'm a very big fan of facelets and this is one more cool feature.